# `tooManyRequests` Error in SWIFT using Amadeus API

Tags: swift, httprequest, amadeus

I'm using `Amadeus` API for flight search. Amadeus API requires that requests must not be more frequent than 1/100ms. I use the following code to limit the request frequency

```swift
        for depDate in depDates{
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                AmadeusHelper.sharedInstance().searchAFlight(depAirport: depAirport, arrAirport: arrAirport, depDate: depDate, airlineCode: airlineCode, flightNumber: flightNum) { result in
                    switch result{
                    case .failure(let err):
                        print(err)
                    case .success(let flightOffer):
                        if let json = flightOffer.get(){
                            flightCandidate.offers?.append(json)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

The above `for-loop` runs 4 loops. The `searchAFlight` function is essentially a wrapper of `HTTP request`. `asyncAfter` function will delay each request by 1 second. I thought this would be enough. However, I still get `tooManyRequests` error. When I was debugging, I followed the code step by step, which should took much longer to send out the requests. The requests should spread out across several minutes, long enough to satisfy the 100ms interval. Did I do something wrong here? Thanks.

===========Update=========

Based on Eric's comments, I changed the code to the following

```swift
        var timeNow = DispatchTime.now() // each request is delayed with an increasing interval 
        for (index, depDate) in depDates.enumerated(){
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: timeNow + Double(1*index)) {
                AmadeusHelper.sharedInstance().searchAFlight(depAirport: depAirport, arrAirport: arrAirport, depDate: depDate, airlineCode: airlineCode, flightNumber: flightNum) { result in
                    switch result{
                    case .failure(let err):
                        print(err)
                    case .success(let flightOffer):
                        if let json = flightOffer.get(){
                            flightCandidate.offers?.append(json)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, I still get `tooManyRequest` error.

Comment: All `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)` is doing is that it offsets the moment the requests will *start*, but they still are executed very fast in sequence (because of the loop) once the first one has started (they're all offset with the same time).

Comment: Thanks @EricAya Do you have any suggestion for doing the four requests with required intervals among them? Timer?

Comment: Hi @EricAya I tried single requests (not using `semaphore`, but just send only one request), it works fine. I will try `semaphore` and `timer`. But one thing here is that, the API sometimes doesn't call the completion handler. The example you gave has a `semaphore.signal()` in the completion handler. Any suggestion to add some timeout logic here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was:

```
for depDate in depDates {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { ... }
}
```

That will not work because you are scheduling all of those iterations to start one second from now, not one second from each other.

You then attempted:

```
for (index, depDate) in depDates.enumerated() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index)) { ... }
}
```

That is likely closer to what you want, but is subject to “timer coalescing”, a feature where the OS will start grouping/coalescing dispatched blocks together. This is a great power saving feature, but will circumvent the desire to have delays between the requests. Also, you’re going to have troubles if you ever want to cancel some of these subsequent requests (without complicating the code a bit, at least).

---

The simplest solution is to adopt a recursive pattern, where you trigger the next request in the completion handler of the prior one.

```
func searchFlight(at index: Int = 0) {
    guard index < depDates.count else { return }

    let depDate = depDates[index]

    AmadeusHelper.sharedInstance().searchAFlight(depDate: depDate, ...) { result in
        defer {
            if index < (depDates.count - 1) {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in 
                    self?.searchFlight(at: index + 1)
                }
            }
        }

        switch result { ... }
    }
}
```

There’s no coalescing of these calls. Also, this has the virtue that the delay for a subsequent request will be based upon when the prior one *finished,* not after the prior one was *issued* (which can be an issue if scheduling a bunch of these requests up-front).

That having been said, I would advise that you direct this inquiry to Amadeus. I wouldn’t be surprised if this 100ms limitation was introduced to prevent people from mining their database through their API. I also wouldn’t be surprised if they have other, undocumented, techniques for identifying excessive requests (e.g. number of requests per hour, per 24 hours, etc.). The question of “why am I receiving `tooManyRequest` error” is best directed to them.

Comment: Thank you @Rob !  I'm surprised that iOS does `grouping/coalescing dispatched blocks` when Timer is used. Isn't `Timer` designed to perform tasks repeatedly with intervals? Sending requests at intervals should be a very common scenario. How come recursive call is the only solution? In my case, this might not work since the Amadeus API sometimes does not call the completion handler. I don't know why.

Comment: I very much appreciate you providing this solution. I have read hours documents and articles on this issue. Most of the time `Semaphore` was recommended. Do you think 'semaphore' could solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: No, I think semaphores are not a good solution. In fact, they’re often bandied about here on StackOverflow but they’re almost always the wrong solution: Anything that blocks a thread is inherently inefficient (the number of worker threads is quite limited) and, with the slightest misuse, can introduce deadlocks, block main thread, etc. Semaphores have very narrow use cases, and this ain’t one of them.

Comment: Re coalescing timers, with repeating timers they’re not coalesced. And with Timer API and/or GCD timers, you can opt out of coalescing. But `asyncAfter` doesn’t give you that control. This is all academic, as your 100ms window probably starts after the prior request finished, anyway, so you really want it to start after the prior one _finishes_, not when you initiated it.

Comment: “... the Amadeus API sometimes does not call the completion handler.” I find that hard to believe (unless you send too many requests and this might be a precursor to the `tooManyRequest` error). But you can just give your request a reasonable timeout parameter. But if you’re having this sort of problem, that is further argument for you’re needing to take this up with Amadeus, directly.

Comment: Hi @Rob, I didn't have a chance to work on this for a couple of days. By `And with Timer API and/or GCD timers, you can opt out of coalescing`, what do you mean? can you write some pseudo code? Could you also point me to some good articles systematically talking about `asynchronous programming`? I read here and there and hard to get a full picture when it comes to asynchronous programming in SWIFT. Thanks !

Comment: Regarding the `Amadeus` API, I reported some other bugs, which I know where it went wrong after following into their codes. But for this completion handler not getting called, I have no clue. For whatever reason the request is not completed, there should be a report. Since this is my exercise project to learn swift, I have decided not to waste time on waiting responses from third party API developers and move on my learning on other things. But I do want to have a good understanding on asynchronous programming since this is a fundamental part in mobile app development.

Comment: On a general observation on asynchronous patterns, if you provide asynchronous API with completion handler, the completion handler _must_ be called. (Sometimes errors are handled in separate closure or delegate-API called, but something must be called upon failure.) It is a very serious bug if an API has a path of execution in which it never responds. If this is the case with this API, then I think your decision to move on to other API is prudent, because if they've failed on such a fundamental design consideration, that's probably just the canary in the coal mine.

Comment: Re coalescing, `asyncAfter` applies a [10% leeway by default](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/4659503fee11a3c0cad79a771de53dbde0ca92cc/src/source.c#L1340). But `Timer` has a `tolerance` parameter (that defaults to 0) and GCD timers can apply a `flags` of [`.strict`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource/timerflags/1780877-strict) to avoid coalescing. But that's all academic, as you generally shouldn't be scheduling a bunch of tasks up front (because unwinding all them in the event of cancelation is a hassle).

Comment: Thank you @Rob! I guess the recursive function is the way to go.